# Developer Story: Open source should allow issues or PRs to be selected

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Currently when adding a new "Open source" item to your developer story timeline, it only allows a repository to be selected.

It could be that I contributed an awesome PR or issue to a project that I want to promote on my story. It would be nice to have a first-class experience to accomplish this.

Comment: Strongly approve. A perversity I've observed is that the perceived benefit to hireability of having an "open source portfolio" incentivises people to publish useless toy projects of no practical value to anyone. By all means follow a tutorial to create yet another TODO app in React for the sake of learning React, but don't expect me to be impressed if you put it on your GitHub account. Meaty contributions to third party projects that solve real problems are both more useful to the world and a far better demonstration of your mettle. Let's do our bit to fix the incentives.

Comment: Github doesn't have a good page (that i can find) for showing all your contributions to a repo. Being able to show one really good PR would be okay, but you might have made many smaller ones that you'd like to feature as a group.

Comment: @RichardGarside It does: https://github.com/userX/repo/commits?author=userY ([random live sample](https://github.com/github/fetch/commits?author=mislav)) shows commits of userY. Via the GUI you can reach it by navigating to the contributors page from a repo and then clicking on the number of commits of a specific contributor. I admit that it's probably nothe best UI for showing off, though.

Comment: I've removed the status-review tag from this post, since the Developer Story feature no longer exists.